# How can I configure Ubuntu with GNOME 3 to dim screen when charger is unplugged?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, brightness, battery, tlp

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 (with GNOME 3) on my new HP laptop, and I noticed that the screen does not dim when the charger is unplugged.

Is there a way to set up two brightness profiles, one for AC adapter, and one for battery?

Most of the tutorials say to install tlp, but from what I notice it does not change the brightness level... it seems to increase the battery life though.

Comment: It has been *requested* for TLP all right (but you may want to read the whole thing, there are several conflicts to overcome): https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/190

Comment: @MichaelBay, so the conclusion from this is 17.10 does not have it by default, and the TLP guys don't want to do it, because of possible conflicts

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Like so many things in life, it's complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Dim On Battery Power](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/947/dim-on-battery-power/).

It lets you set two separate brightness levels, one for AC, another for battery.